How do I best fit my linear mixed effect model with lmer() from the "lme4" R-package?
So, I'm pretty new to R and modeling with lmer from the "lme4" package. I would love some help on how to fit my model to answer my research question; if different grab types are comparable, i.e. do grab have an effect on my response variables abundance, biomass and species richness of benthic invertebrates. I want to compare if a common soft sediment sampling method using a van Veen grab is different from using another sampling method called the Ekman grab.
I have data from field sampling bottom sediment with the two grabs at three different stations (with different depths), and I took 10 samples with Ekman and 5 samples with van Veen at each station. So, in total, I have 45 samples; 30 with Ekman and 15 with van Veen. I am only interested in the effect of grab on response variables but I want to account for the variance between stations in my model. Is this a reasonable model fit using lmer()? I want to account for random intercepts for station but also a possible interaction between grab and station. Or does another model fit better? It is not a very complex model, I only have two factors, but I am unsure how to fit my model the best way. If I want to treat "Station" as random, is the interaction also supposed to be random? Thanks!
lmer.model5 <- lmer(Abundance ~ Grab + (1|Station) + (1|Grab:Station)
I have tried fitting several models, but I am unsure with which one to go forward with. I need some guidance on how to fit my model to answer my research question.
lmer.model1 <- lmer(Abundance ~ Grab + (1|Station))
lmer.model2 <- lmer(Abundance ~ Grab * Station + (1|Station))
lmer.model3 <- lmer(Abundance ~ Grab + Station + (1|Station))
lmer.model4 <- lmer(Abundance ~ Grab + (Grab|Station))
lmer.model5 <- lmer(Abundance ~ Grab + (1|Station) + (1|Grab:Station))
Cross posted

Apologies, but what is grab in this context? I don't think that's clear from the question.

@ShawnHemelstrand Thanks for your comment! A grab is a soft sediment sampling method, like e.g. a van Veen grab or an Ekman grab, and is used to take a sediment sample of the seafloor and which most often is sieved to retrieve sediment-living fauna. See e.g. van Veen grab: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Veen_grab_sampler

A few observations / points:

Models 2 and 3 both specify Station as a fixed effect and a random effect (specifically a grouping factor for fitting random intercepts). I am yet to find a scenario where this is good idea. You need to choose whether to include Station as a fixed effect or a random effect. There are many threads on this site which discuss this. Here are a couple:

What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect in mixed effect models?
Questions about how random effects are specified in lmer

The stated research question is:


"do grab have an effect on my response variables abundance, biomass and species richness of benthic invertebrates. I want to compare if a common soft sediment sampling method using a van Veen grab is different from using another sampling method called the Ekman grab"

and

"I am only interested in the effect of grab on response variables"

Thus, it seems clear that you are interested in the fixed effect of grab.The model estimates for this will allow you to answer the question: "What is the association between different grabs and Abundance
But then you also say:

"... but I want to account for the variance between stations in my model"

This is where random intercepts for Station come in, which should help to handle the non-independence of observations within each Station

You are also interested in "a possible interaction between grab and station"

In the mixed model framework one way to achieve this is by specifying random slopes for Grab, so each Station can have it's own association fore grab with the outcome.  It's important to verify whether allowing the Grab effect to vary by station adds to the model's fit. If the variance for the random slopes is near zero, it suggests that the association between grab type and abundance is consistent across stations, and a simpler random intercept model might suffice. AIC/BIC (or a likelihood ratio test) might also be used to check this.
Putting it together, we have the following candidate model:
Abundance ~ Grab + (Grab|Station)

which is your model 4 :)
I hope this helps:)

Thank you so much for a great explanation @Robert Long! :)
